# Which element is causing the horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: css

Please have a look and help me out, I've been looking at my css for an hour and can't figure it out... [link to external url](http://www.ht-webcreations.com/violak/index.php?lang=en)

Comment: What horizontal scroll bar? Which browser(s) are you seeing it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layout.css replace

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: url(../images/tail_main.gif) repeat-x center top;
    clear: both;
}
```

with

```
#footer{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: url(../images/tail_main.gif) repeat-x center top;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for the problem in the upper sections of my pages, It hadn't occured to me tha t the footer div was causing it...

Answer (score 2):

The footer is causing it. Change

```
width: 100%;
```

to:

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is also correct but I had to accept the 1st one submitted by Envy.

Answer (score 1):

It's the width of your footer that's creating the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is also correct but I had to accept the 1st one submitted by Envy.

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
width: 100%
```

from footer. This does the job.

In layout.css, remove line 124.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is also correct but I had to accept the 1st one submitted by Envy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your footer's width property or set it to auto. You can't have 100% width to element with padding set to constant pixels.

Other workaround is to use width:90%; and padding:0 5%; to have 100% width

Cheers,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in  element. padding: 10px (layout.css line 123)